# splitting all the columns in a dataframe based on their value and delimiter

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(s1=c("a","a/b","b","a","a/b"),s2=c("ab/bb","bb","ab","ab","bb"),s3=c("Doa","Doa","Dob/Doa","Dob/Doa","Dob"))
```

> ```
>    s1    s2      s3
> 1   a ab/bb     Doa
> 2 a/b    bb     Doa
> 3   b    ab Dob/Doa
> 4   a    ab Dob/Doa
> 5 a/b    bb     Dob
> ```

Each column could take one of two values or both separated by a "/". I would like to break these down into binary sets of columns based on their values.

The desired data frame would be:

> ```
>    a   b   ab   bb   Doa   Dob
> 1  1   0    1    1    1    0
> 2  1   1    0    1    1    0
> 3  0   1    1    0    1    1
> 4  1   0    1    0    1    1
> 5  1   1    0    1    0    1
> ```

I tried doing this with tidyr::separate and tapply, though it got fairly complicated as I had to specify column names for every pair. There were many columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another approach is to use`pivot_longer` into 'long' format and then use `separate_rows` to split the 'value' column and reshape into 'wide' format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -rn) %>%
    separate_rows(value) %>%
    mutate(i1 = 1) %>%
    select(-name) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = i1, values_fill = list(i1 = 0)) %>%
    select(-rn)
# A tibble: 5 x 6
#      a    ab    bb   Doa     b   Dob
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     1     1     1     0     0
#2     1     0     1     1     1     0
#3     0     1     0     1     1     1
#4     1     1     0     1     0     1
#5     1     0     1     0     1     1
```

---

Or using `base R` with `table` and `strsplit`

```
+(table(stack(setNames(strsplit(as.character(unlist(df)), "/",
       fixed = TRUE), c(row(df))))[2:1]) > 0)
#  values
#ind a ab b bb Doa Dob
#  1 1  1 0  1   1   0
#  2 1  0 1  1   1   0
#  3 0  1 1  0   1   1
#  4 1  1 0  0   1   1
#  5 1  0 1  1   0   1
```

Comment: Could you explain the `+table`?

Comment: @camille The `> 0` returns a logical matrix.  So, I am just coercing it to binary with `+`

Comment: Why not just `t(table(stack(setNames(strsplit(as.character(unlist(df)), "/",
                                    fixed = TRUE), c(row(df))))))` ?

Comment: @Matt It is doing the transpose, and I am just reordering the `stack` columns

Comment: What is the default delimiter with separate_rows? Does "[^[:alnum:].]" include "/"

Comment: @user171558 it would check for any values that are not (`^`) alpha numeric or `.`.  Reason it avoids `.` would be - `.` can be part of double

Answer (score 6):

First make sure your data is character and not factor. Then split into one data.frame for each row and for each of those rows, take the str_split on `'/'`, set the names equal to the values, and make it a list. Now you can bind these results together, and set all non-na values to 1 at the end.

```
library(tidyverse) # dplyr, + stringr for str_split, + purrr for map

df %>% 
  mutate_all(as.character) %>% 
  split(seq(nrow(.))) %>% 
  map(~ str_split(., '/') %>% unlist %>% setNames(., .) %>% as.list) %>% 
  bind_rows %>% 
  mutate_all(~as.numeric(!is.na(.)))

# # A tibble: 5 x 6
#       a    ab    bb   Doa     b   Dob
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     1     1     1     0     0
# 2     1     0     1     1     1     0
# 3     0     1     0     1     1     1
# 4     1     1     0     1     0     1
# 5     1     0     1     0     1     1
```

Another similar option (same output)

```
df %>% 
  mutate_all(as.character) %>% 
  split(seq(nrow(.))) %>% 
  map(~ str_split(., '/') %>% unlist %>% table %>% as.list) %>% 
  bind_rows %>% 
  mutate_all(replace_na, 0)
```

Or you could convert to long first then back to wide, similar to akrun's answer

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
library(magrittr)

melt(df[, r := 1:.N], 'r') %>% 
  .[, .(value = strsplit(value, '/')[[1]]), .(r, variable)] %>% 
  dcast(r ~ value, fun.aggregate = length)

#    r Doa Dob a ab b bb
# 1: 1   1   0 1  1 0  1
# 2: 2   1   0 1  0 1  1
# 3: 3   1   1 0  1 1  0
# 4: 4   1   1 1  1 0  0
# 5: 5   0   1 1  0 1  1
```